# using CoGbkResult with PAssert.containsInAnyOrder()

Tags: apache-beam

I'm trying to cover with tests a Apache Beam function which returns accepts and return KV:

```java
public class ChangeKeyFn extends DoFn<KV<String, CoGbkResult>, KV<String, CoGbkResult>> {

     @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element KV<String, CoGbkResult> element, OutputReceiver<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> receiver) {
       ...
     }
}

  PAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder(...)
```

But always having assertion error. However I'm pretty sure that function works correctly.

```java
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: iterable over [<KV{val1, [[{col2=val2, col1=val1}], [{colB=valB, colA=valA}]]}>] in any order
     but: Not matched: <KV{val1, [[{col2=val2, col1=val1}], [{colB=valB, colA=valA}]]}>
```

Most probably root cause that CoGbkResult is not overriding equals method:

```java
CoGbkResult gbkRes = CoGbkResult.of(new TupleTag<String>("tuple1"), Collections.singletonList( "string1" ));

CoGbkResult gbkRes2 = CoGbkResult.of(new TupleTag<String>("tuple1"), Collections.singletonList( "string1" ));

assertTrue(gbkRes.equals(gbkRes2));
```

Any reason for CoGbkResult to not override equals method? How to use CoGbkResult with PAssert.containsInAnyOrder?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to perform required asserts thru satisfies function call

```
PAssert.that(output).satisfies(new SatisfyFunction());
```

SatisfyFunction obtains whole collection inside Iterable input:

```
    public static final class SatisfyFunction1 implements SerializableFunction<Iterable<KV<String,CoGbkResult>>,Void> {

        @Override
        public Void apply(Iterable<KV<String, CoGbkResult>> inputs) {
            int counter = 0;
            HashSet<String> keys =  new HashSet<String>();
            for(KV<String, CoGbkResult> input : inputs) {
                counter++;
                keys.add(input.getKey());
            }
            assertEquals(3, counter);
            assertEquals(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("U1", "U2", "U3")), keys);
            return null;
        }

    }
```